# differences of pdf sync in TexShop

Tags: texshop, forward-inverse-search

I have this stupid issue that bothers me. I use TexShop on two different computers, and when I command-click the source code (i.e., a forward-inverse search), each computer behaves differently.

One of them marks the pdf-text with a red circle:
[image]

The other "highlights" the pdf-text:
[image]

I wasn't able to find out where the difference comes from, and how to change it.
Both computers run snow leopard. I think I used the same distribution in both, but it is possible that they use different distribution.

Any ideas how to control the way the selected text is marked?

**EDIT**:
The one that is all red runs on OS X 10.6.8, Texshop2.47, Texlive2010  and gives red circle for all the sync methods.
The one that has highlight runs on 10.6.8, Texshop2.47, Texlive2011  and gives highlight only when the "syncTex ≥2010" option is selected.

Answer (score 3):

The difference seems to lie both in the version of TeXShop you are running and in the method chosen in the preferences Typsetting -> Sync Method. With TeXShop version 2.47 (the latest version that runs under Snow Leopard) if you choose SyncTex (≥ 2010) you get highlighting as in your second example.  If you choose any of the other three options, you get the red circle, as in your first example.

With TeXShop version 3.16 under Mountain Lion (and I presume Lion) you get a red circle with all methods.  Given your comments, I suspect then that one machine is running 2.47 and the other machine is running 3.16.

Comment: both are set to SyncTex (≥ 2010)

Comment: On my system (running Snow Leopard) I can reproduce both behaviours by switching these options.  Have you tried switching on your Snow Leopard machine?

Comment: On the Lion, all options cause the red-circle. I don't have the leopard next to me right now, I'll check it later.

Comment: BTW, the Pdf Sync (<2010) option doesn't work at all. The other 3 option give a red circle, as I mentioned.

Comment: No, that's not it. I always get the same red circle on Snow Leopard (10.6.8) with TexShop 2.47 (using Texlive2010).

Comment: Well the only difference then is your distribution.  I have TL 2012 installed. Do both machines have the same distribution too?

Comment: I tend to think it is a bug of TexShop. After changing back and forth between `PdfSync` and `both` options, the inverse search stopped working at all. I manually added `-synctex=1` to the command line. This brought back the inverse search *AND* changed the red circle into highlighting.